# label mean lines in ggplot that are mapped in a group

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, line

I have density plots for each shift and year. The means are plotted by grouping in a df called mu. I also add vertical reference lines which I can label without issue but I cannot seem to get the labels on the grouped vertical lines. You will see my latest attempt which throws an error  "Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (134): x"

My code

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(dplyr)
    df <- read.csv("f4_bna_no_cup.csv")

    head(df)
  ï..n   yr s     ys      x
1    1 2021 1 2021-1 116.83
2    2 2021 1 2021-1 114.83
3    3 2021 1 2021-1 115.50
4    4 2021 1 2021-1 115.42
5    5 2021 1 2021-1 115.58
6    6 2021 1 2021-1 115.58
#summarize means by ys (year-shift)
    mu <- df %>% 
      group_by(ys,s) %>%
      summarise(grp.mean = mean(x))  
    mu
    ys    s     grp.mean
  <chr>  <int>    <dbl>
1 2021-1     1     116.
2 2021-2     2     117.
3 2022-1     1     114.
4 2022-2     2     115.

llab<-mu

    shift <- c("Shift 1", "Shift 2")
#density charts on df
    ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x,group =ys, fill = yr, color = yr)) +
    geom_density(alpha = 0.4) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits=c(112,120))+
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = grp.mean), data = mu, linetype = "dashed", size = 0.5)  +
    geom_text(aes(x=llab$grp.mean, y=.6), label = llab$ys) +   #this throws the error
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept=114.8), linetype="dashed", size=0.5, color = 'green3') +
    geom_text(aes(x=114.8, y=.6), label = "Target", angle = 90, color="black",size=3) +
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept=114.1), linetype="solid", size=0.5, color = 'limegreen') +
    geom_text(aes(x=114.1, y=.55), label = "Potential", angle = 90, color="black",size=3 ) +
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept=113.4), linetype="solid", size=0.5, color = 'firebrick3') +
    geom_text(aes(x=113.4, y=.62), label = "Label wt", angle = 90, 
         color="black",size=3, family = "Times New Roman", vjust=0) +
    facet_grid(
    .~s,
    labeller = labeller(
      s = c(`1` = "Shift 1", `2` = "Shift 2")
  
    ))+
 
    theme_light()+
    theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Output so far...I'm so close.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Persistence pays off. I figured it out and thought I would share it in case someone else has a similar problem:
All code remains the same as in my question except a slight change to grouping for the mu df, AND replace the line that I noted as throwing the error as follows:

```
#small change to group_by, retaining yr
mu <- df %>% 
  group_by(yr,s,ys) %>%
  summarise(grp.mean = mean(x))
```

Replace: *geom_text(aes(x=llab$grp.mean, y=.6), label = llab$ys)*, with

```
geom_text(data = mu, aes(label = yr), x = mu$grp.mean, y = .60, color = "black", angle = 90, vjust = 0)
```